# show data in another cell after press enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have this code

```
<tr>
                                <td  width="300">
                                        <label for="tag">Model</label>
                                </td>
                                        <td>
                                                <td width="10">:</td>
                                        </td>
                                <td>
                                        <td>
                                                <td width="450" align="left">
                                                <input type="text" id="tags1" name="model">
                                                </td>
                                        </td>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
```

if i type inside textfield "E" i want inside another cell show like:

```
<tr>
       <td><label><h6>this version <input type.......show E>
                  <br>87.5-108.0</br></h6></label>
        </td>
</tr>
```

but if type "J" will show:

```
<tr>
       <td><label><h6>this version <input type......show J>
                  <br>87.5-107.9</br></h6></label>
        </td>
</tr>
```

what's code that can make it works after press <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Comment: you have a either broken or confused markup of <td>'s

Comment: Close Voters: This is a real question, it just needs a little more explanation.  If @klox can supply further info then we can help.

Comment: so is the ENTER key required or just "E" or "J" without enter will change the another cell?

Comment: @Jian :i agree with u're answer..

Comment: @reigel: are u still remember my project which separate a barcode??my project still continue..after i type KD-R411ED..i want script can read two character from behind ("ED")...i want it make other cell show "87.5-108.0"....this is my code after try to combine the answer from jian and ungarida:
var model=$("#tags1").val();
var version [0]="JD";
var version [1]="ED";
var version [2]="EED";
var version [3]="EXD";

each version
if (model.lastIndexof(version)!=-1) {
select version
case "JD":$("#range").html("87.5-107.9");
break;
case "ED":$("#range").html("87.5-108.0");
break;
end select}
end each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can follow this sample:

```
<table><tr><td><input type="text" id="aTextInput"></td><td id="theValue"></td></tr></table>

<script>

    document.getElementById("aTextInput").onchange = function(event) {
        //console.log(event)
        //console.log(document.getElementById("aTextInput").value)
        if (document.getElementById("aTextInput").value == "E")
            document.getElementById("theValue").innerHTML = "87.5-108.0";
        else if (document.getElementById("aTextInput").value == "J")
            document.getElementById("theValue").innerHTML = "87.5-107.9";
        else
            document.getElementById("theValue").innerHTML = "";     // clear it out if it had value before
    }

</script>
```

Comment: actually i type like this "KD-R411E" and i want "E" character in that word can effect that cell and show like u're answer...how must i do?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you what to show and where, but you could try this code for the first part when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
$("#tags1").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        var input = $("#tags1").val();
        switch(input)
        {
            case "E":
                // show E
            break;
            case "J":
                // show J
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: i'll modify and combine u're answer n jian lin